# SQL not liking the word SplitList

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does SQL not reconice SplitList?

This is my code and SQL dont like the word SplitList.

Message is "Invalid object name"

```
Where FirstName IN (Select * from SplitList(@CustomerName, ','))
```

Comment: When SplitList is a table valued function without an explit schema, call it in this way: `dbo.SplitList(@CustomerName, ',')`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Should be an answer probably...

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing like `SplitList` built-in to T-SQL or ANSI SQL.

The code sample that you're using appears to assume that you already have a user-defined function called `SplitList`.

If you *do* already have a user-defined `SplitList` function then you probably just need to specify its schema when you call it:

```
WHERE FirstName IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitList(@CustomerName, ','))
-- or
WHERE FirstName IN (SELECT * FROM yourschema.SplitList(@CustomerName, ','))
```

Answer (score 3):

If `SplitList` is a table valued function without an explit schema, call it in this way:

```
Select * from dbo.SplitList(@CustomerName, ',')
```

If no schema is provided, SQL Server will assume `dbo` is the default schema.

By the way, you can change the schema of a database object in this way:

```
ALTER SCHEMA [NewSchema] TRANSFER dbo.SplitList
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx